# "Loop will run at most once (loop increment never executed)" C++

Tags: c++, loops

I am receiving a "Loop will run at most once (loop increment never executed)" error causing the loop not to work and I am clueless as to why? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
else if (Selection == 10)

{
    if ((CompareArray[0] == 0 && CompareArray[1] == 0) ||

        (CompareArray[0] == 1 && CompareArray[1] == 0))
    {
        for(i = 2; i < 6; i++)
        {
            if (CompareArray[i] == 0)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            return 30;
        }
    }

    else if (CompareArray[0] == 0)
    {
        for (i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        {
            if (CompareArray[i] == 0)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            return 30;
        }
    }

    else
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            if (CompareArray[i] == 0)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            return 30;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems strange to have to ask this - but which loop?

Comment: All loops return on the first iteration.

Comment: When whatever mysterious program gave you that error, it would also have identified what line it's complaining about. Post the **full** error. Anyway, if the code were not so meaningless, you should also have posted an example of what you put into `CompareArray`! Read the Help Centre to learn what an MCVE is.

Comment: Do you know what `return` does? Also, try stepping through the code in a debugger, you may realise what the issue is.

Comment: All the loops. They all return right away.

Comment: The error appears for every for loop

Comment: @Lessa You might want to read the comments again. It was already stated two times that every loop you have has a return statement that is executed in the first iteration. A return statement will end the function and thus the loop.

Comment: You probably want the return 30; out of the for loop

Comment: Google search on subject immediately points to the duplicate, why you do not bother to do even minimal research before asking?

Answer (score 1):

You will know why it doesn't work when you read this:
[return statement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return)

### Syntax

`attr(optional) return expression(optional) ;` (1)

`attr(optional) return braced-init-list ;` (2) (since C++11)

- *attr(C++11)* -   optional sequence of any number of attributes
- *expression*  -   expression, convertible to the function return type
- *braced-init-list*    -   brace-enclosed list of initializers and other braced-init-lists

### Explanation

1) Evaluates the expression, terminates the current function and returns the result of the expression to the caller, after implicit conversion to the function return type. The expression is optional in functions whose return type is (possibly cv-qualified) void, in constructors and in destructors.

2) Uses copy-list-initialization to construct the return value of the function.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19559332)

Comment: @TomAranda First of all, it doesn't make sense to explain what C/C++ return statement is to a person which wants to write a complete C++ program, nor such answer will help anyone else. The same way you can't teach math someone who doesn't know what numbers are. Regarding the link you're partially right. It might be unavailable one day but documentation for C/C++ return statement will **never** be unavailable and it can be found easily any time.

Comment: @user463035818 I don't think so. This answer is deliberately made in this way. The answer instructs where to find basic of basics documentation and you should never attempt to write even a single line of C or C++ code before knowing what return statement does.

Comment: @BJovke sorry I cannot follow you. " This answer is deliberately made in this way." ... when i commented this answer was made in a completely different way: It was basically a link-only, hence my comment (and downvote). Since you edited my comment is obsolete (and maybe also the downvote ;)

Comment: @BJovke: I recommend you read this [meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) on why the SO community frowns on link-only  answers.  Your edit greatly improved your answer BTW.

Comment: @TomAranda I agree with you and the post (you answered with the link now) but the question is of poor quality and there's really no answer to this question that could ever help anyone else with similar problem. It's not the point to blindly answer the question which was asked in a wrong way, and, **especially** when the person asking the question did not take a minimal effort to search about the subject on internet. And this subject has millions of answers. Next time I'll just downvote the question and let someone else waste their time answering it.

Comment: @TomAranda And, btw, my time I'm giving for answering questions like this one is far more expensive than the time of the person asking the question. Even worse is the fact that the person asking something like this probably wasted **no time** to search for the solution. "I'll just won't turn my brain on **at all** and post a C++ question on SO". And we're talking about C++ which is not a pleasant summer walk in a park.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:

```
    for (i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (CompareArray[i] == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return 30;
    }
```

Inside your `for` loop, you always have a return value that will return a value on the first iteration.  It will always return either `0`, or `30`, then not continue to the next iteration.

You probably want this:

```
    for (i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (CompareArray[i] == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 30;
```

Notice the return value is outside of the for loop, which will happen if no value in your loop equals 0.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what is your goal, so can't suggest a solution that you might want, but to avoid the error and to ensure exectution, you could modify your code as follows (also some small changes make the code succinct):

```
else if (Selection == 10)
{
    int start = 0;
    if ((CompareArray[0] == 0 && CompareArray[1] == 0) ||
        (CompareArray[0] == 1 && CompareArray[1] == 0))
        start = 2;
    else if(CompareArray[0] == 0)
        start = 1;

    for(i = start; i < (start+4); i++)
    {
        if (CompareArray[i] == 0)
            return 0;
    }

    return 30;
}
```